# How can I reference the variable I have just defined in RecordSet.Find Methods?

Tags: vba, ms-access, syntax

I am trying to debug this sub where I utlize the variable value I assign with an InputBox in the Recordset.Find methods but I keep getting a runtime error as it will not recognize the variable Prod defined below.

I have tried putting Prod in single quotes and I don't get a runtime error but it also ignores the criteria just giving me the first item in the whole record set
''''

```
Sub MoveAround()
'declaration of recordset variable and Prod variable
Dim MyR As Recordset
Dim Prod As String

'Setting Recordset to Current DB with Table Name and dynamic view
Set MyR = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("813ActiveErrors", dbOpenDynaset)

'Prompts user for value of Item
Prod = InputBox("Please Input the Item")

'Finds first record in record set where Item=value of prod
'I keep getting an error here Where it says: The MS Access database engine 'does not recognize 'Prod' as a valid field name or expression

MyR.FindFirst ("[Item] = Prod")

MyR.Close
Set MyR = Nothing



End Sub
```

''''

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate:

```
MyR.FindFirst "[Item] = '" & Prod & "'"
```